# Easy way to stop a task from executing after certain amount of time(Xamarin.Android)

Tags: time, task, execution

On button click I want to open a `ProgressDialog` which will show until a `task` is being executed, but I want to be able to stop the task even if it hasn't been completed after certain amount of time. I saw a lot of solutions on internet but they are very long. I want to know if there is an easier way.

here is my `On Button Click` event:

```
private async void Btn_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

    var mDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mDialog.SetMessage("Loading data...");
    mDialog.SetCancelable(false);
    mDialog.Show();

    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    cts.CancelAfter(5000);

    Task<int> task = new Task<int>(Foo, cts.Token);
    task.Start();

    int integer = await task;

    mDialog.Dismiss();

    txtView.Text = integer.ToString();


}
```

And here is my method which will execute in the task:

```
public int Foo()
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
    return 100;
}
```

Is it possible to stop the task at the `5th second` of its execution without changing a lot the code I've just pasted, for example with only passing some time or object to the task's constructor, and also without making the `Foo()` method `async`

Answer (score 1):

You can try

step 1. Adding a timer

```
    Timer _timer = new Timer {Interval = 5000};
                        _timer.Elapsed += OnTimeEvent;
                        _timer.Start();
```

step 2.Cancel the task on timer event

```
    private void OnTimeEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
            cts .Cancel();
    }
```